# Liferay on SQL Server suggestions

Tags: sql-server, liferay

does anyone has any experience of installing Liferay using SQL Server as database ? Any particular problem with installation or performance ? Which version can I use? Maybe I have to use a legacy instance SQL Server 2000

Thanks

Comment: Liferay is a provider of market leading open source portal, web publishing, content, and collaboration solutions to the enterprise.

Comment: Denis, sorry for my imprecison, i mean Liferay Enterprise Portal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Liferay can be configured with any database that supports JDBC driver, which you can download from Microsoft to SQL Server 2000. 
 
See liferay configuration details from here: http://www.liferay.com/web/guest/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Database%20Configuration#section-Database+Configuration-IncludingTheJDBCDriver 

I have installed the portal using the provided Hyper SQL and migrated to both DB2 and MySql without a problem *(demo data needs to be deleted anyway after deployment).*

Comment: Thanks for your reply, i've also installed Liferay Portal with MySql many times, but i have no experience of it running on SqlServer, so i was asking for any comment/experience about it.